# How to correct the command for PHP 7.0.* in following PHP cli and git installation?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, php, git, php-cli

I'm using **Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS 64-bit** OS on my machine.

I just updated all the softwares and packages installed on my system by running following commands from the terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now I'm using **PHP 7.0.5**, the latest current stable version of PHP.

For checking it I run the following command from the terminal :

```
php -v

PHP 7.0.5-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Now I was trying to install Composer(The Project Dependency Management Software). As a prerequisite it needs **cli and Git to be installed** so for it I typed in following command and got following error. How to resolve this error?

```
sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli git

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
curl set to manually installed.
git is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-cli : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14) but 5.5.32+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
            Recommends: php5-readline but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The error I want to resolve is as below from above output :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-cli : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14) but 5.5.32+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
            Recommends: php5-readline but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Someone please provide me the correct command I need to run from the terminal and remove this error.

I think it's occurring since I'm no more using **PHP 5.5.9**. Just provide me the necessary command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.0 packages has been renamed, so you are looking either for `apt-get install php-cli` to install dependency package that will pull default PHP version, or just `apt-get install php7.0-cli`. I recommend the former.